# How to change the code of a batch file so that it can be executed from a network resource instead of root of a drive?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need that code to run directly from the computer (shared network folder) and not from a USB drive which is mandatory as it can be seen in the code.

```
set pathToScript=%~d0
set pathToRessources=%~d0\Resources
set pathToGPO=%~d0\TemplateGPO

cscript //B "%windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs" /ato 

mkdir "%WINDIR%\display"
```

How to change the code of this batch file so that it can be executed from a directory on a network resource instead of root of a drive?

Comment: There is nothing in the code that requires it running from a USB drive (just a Remark stating that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batch file must be run from root of a drive because of the command lines:

```
set pathToScript=%~d0
set pathToRessources=%~d0\Resources
set pathToGPO=%~d0\TemplateGP
```

Those three lines should be changed to:

```
set "pathToScript=%~dp0"
set "pathToRessources=%~dp0Resources"
set "pathToGPO=%~dp0TemplateGPO"
```

Then the batch files can be successfully executed from any directory of a local drive. But the batch file would still fail to execute successfully from a directory of a network resource accessed using a UNC path because of the command line:

```
cd /d "%pathToScript%"
```

Windows prevents by default that a directory on a network resource accessed with a UNC path is set as current directory for compatibility reasons for executables not supporting that the current directory is a directory of which path does not start with a drive letter and a colon. The solution is using `pushd` and `popd` instead of `cd`.

The modified batch file which can be executed from really any directory with local administrative privileges:

```
@echo off
rem RUN AS ADMIN
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "pathToScript=%~dp0"
set "pathToRessources=%~dp0Resources"
set "pathToGPO=%~dp0TemplateGPO"

%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe //B "%SystemRoot%\System32\slmgr.vbs" /ato

mkdir "%SystemRoot%\display"

copy /y "%pathToRessources%\Teneris-Background-Bilingual.jpg" "%PUBLIC%\Pictures\"

copy /y "%pathToRessources%\ssText3d.scr" "%PUBLIC%\Pictures\"

copy /y "%pathToRessources%\Teneris-Lock-Bilingual.jpg" "%SystemRoot%\display"

pushd "%pathToScript%"
lgpo.exe /g "%pathToGPO%\{A213BE3C-CA6C-4F72-9235-FC52719EB79F}"
popd

endlocal
%SystemRoot%\System32\shutdown.exe /r /t 15 /c "post config shutdown in less than 30 sec"
```

The three lines

```
pushd "%pathToScript%"
lgpo.exe /g "%pathToGPO%\{A213BE3C-CA6C-4F72-9235-FC52719EB79F}"
popd
```

can be perhaps changed to just

```
"%pathToScript%lgpo.exe" /g "%pathToGPO%\{A213BE3C-CA6C-4F72-9235-FC52719EB79F}"
```

if the executable `lgpo.exe` can be executed also from a directory different to its storage location which would make the batch file faster and would be also better if the batch file is executed using a group policy or a scheduled task.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~d0` which references the drive of argument 0, i.e. the drive on which batch file is stored respectively the network resource on starting the batch file using a UNC path and `%~dp0` which references drive and path of argument 0 which is the full qualified path of the batch file always ending with a backslash.
- `cscript /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `mkdir /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `shutdown /?`

I don't know if `lgpo.exe` supports also executing it with `/?` as parameter to get displayed the help of this application.